# login form design problems in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a login form code in an ASP MVC program.
I have two problems.
1)login form is not centered.
2)form-controls are not centered in the login form. I noticed when I put borders for form-group divs they are in the center and also I put border for   They put in the middle too. but I do not know why textboxes do not display in the middle of form.

```
    <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 shadow" style="background-color:#0375b4;">

         <section id="loginForm">

                 @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
        {
                     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                     @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                     <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top:0.75cm">
                         <img class="profile-img" src="~/Content/Images/avatar1.png" />
                     </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
                         <div class="col-md-12">
                             @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "control-label", style = "color:white;" })
                         </div>
                     </div>

                     <div class="form-group ">
                         <div class="col-md-12 ">
                             @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control ", @style = "text-align:left" })
                             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                         </div>
                     </div>


                     <div class="form-group">
                         <div class="col-md-12">
                             @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "control-label", style = "color:white;" })
                         </div>
                     </div>


                     <div class="form-group">
                         <div class="col-md-12">
                             @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "text-align:left" })
                             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                         </div>
                     </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
                         <div class="col-md-12">
                             <div class="checkbox">
                                 @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                                 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { style = "color:white;" })
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>


                         <div class="form-group">
                             <div class="col-md-12">
                                 <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"  />
                             </div>
                         </div>


                 }

                 <div style="height:20px">

                 </div>
```

Comment: I solve centralizing of form-controls by defining a class in bootstrap as follow:

Answer (score 1):

Create following css class

```
div.centered {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
}
```

And set it to your container division.

Comment: @Hossuam Hamdan Thank you for your answer. although I saw the same answer for a question but your answer caused I think deeper and at least solve one of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solve centralizing of form-controls by adding a class in bootstrap.css as follow:

```
 .center_div{
         margin: 0 auto;
          width:80% /* value of your choice which suits your alignment */
  }
```

then I use this class in login form view in

```
<section id="loginForm" class="center_div">
```

and form controls set in the middle of form